# Add camera into Android Fragment like instagram post upload

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-camera2

I would like to add a camera view inside a fragment like instagram does, but when I try my code I get a white screen. I am using the camera2 API for android.

On the other hand, one thing is that is Camerakit apply in Fragment other than activity.?

I have used camerafragment, camerakit and now I am using tectureview for camera in android fragment.

My permissions are in my manifest file..

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
```

I am using the following code in `onCreateView()` method of Fragment:

```
textureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture); 
assert textureView != null;
textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener); 
capture_img = view.findViewById(R.id.button_FAB); 
assert takePictureButton != null;
```

Comment: Did you start the camera in onAttach() method, and stop it in onDettach(). Then could you add the camera fragment's code ?

Comment: I am using the following code in onCreateView() method of Fragment.


        textureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        capture_img = view.findViewById(R.id.button_FAB);
        assert takePictureButton != null;

Comment: And tell me one thing , Can i use camerakit lib in fragment??

Comment: I'd never used this lib, but I found [this](https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android/issues/348). Did you ask for permissions ? (you can add code by editing you question)

Comment: ok i will update question. 
Can you tell me other lib for this purpose?
@An

Comment: Currently I'm using [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat). The have many samples. And recently google push is new [camera lib](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax). So take a look and tell me.